# how get image name by using python open-cv

Tags: python, image, csv, opencv

I am reading one image using cv2.imread() function. I want to store image title that is **10_left.jpeg** in one variable and that name write in one CSV file.
code is as below:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('home/pycharmprojects/diabetic/testing/10_left.jpeg')
print("shape of original image ",img.shape)
cv2.imshow('Orgninal Image',img)
```

Comment: Are you asking about reading/writing the EXIF data or something else?

Comment: How is your csv file formatted? Also you need a ``cv2.waitKey`` after imshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, you want to read the image name from a CSV file and use that to open the image with open-cv? In that case, you'll just need to parse your csv file with [csv module](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/csv/using-the-csv-module-in-python). If your CSV is just rows of image names, this is fairly easy.

```
import cv2
import csv

ifile = open(‘test.csv’, “rb”)
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

imageNames = []
for row in reader
    imageNames.append(row)

img = cv2.imread(imageNames[0])
print("shape of original image ",img.shape)
cv2.imshow('Original Image',img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

If your csv is more involved, the link above should help get you on your way.

Comment: thanks for your solution but you get it wrong. I am reading image by its path by using imread function and that time I want to store its name in CSV file. it's not like I am reading image name from CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class for image object and store actual image and file name in separate variables.

```
class MyImage:
    img = None
    name = ''

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.img = cv2.imread(name)

myImage = MyImage('10_left.jpeg')
```

To write the name in CSV file, simple get the value of myImage.name attribute

Comment: if this solution is the one you wanted, please up-vote and verify as the correct answer
thank you

Comment: I am a beginner with python really don't know about python object-oriented concept. please help me to understand that code and  tell me how to write each name in CSV file cause i have 200 images